# Map Json data by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, stringify

I have a Json data that I want to have in a different format.

My original json data is:

```
{
  "info": {
    "file1": {
      "book1": {
        "lines": {
          "102:0": [
            "102:0"
          ],
          "105:4": [
            "106:4"
          ],
          "106:4": [
            "107:1",
            "108:1"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I want to map it as following:

```
{
  "name": "main",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "file1",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "book1",
          "group": "1",
          "lines": [
            "102",
            "102"
          ],
          [
            "105",
            "106"
          ],
          [
            "106",
            "107",
            "108"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "group": 1,

    }
  ],
  "group": 0
}
```

But the number of books and number of files will be more. Here in the lines the 1st part (before the :) inside the "" is taken ("106:4" becomes "106"). The number from the key goes 1st and then the number(s) from the value goes and make a list (["106", "107", "108"]). The group information is new and it depends on parent-child information. 1st parent is group 0 and so on. The first name ("main") is also user defined.

I tried the following code so far:

```
function build(data) {
    return Object.entries(data).reduce((r, [key, value], idx) => {
      //const obj = {}
      const obj = {
        name: 'main',
        children: [],
        group: 0,
        lines: []
      }

      if (key !== 'reduced control flow') {
        obj.name = key;
        obj.children = build(value)
          if(!(key.includes(":")))
          obj.group = idx + 1;
      } else {
        if (!obj.lines) obj.lines = [];
        Object.entries(value).forEach(([k, v]) => {
          obj.lines.push([k, ...v].map(e => e.split(':').shift()))
        })
      }

      r.push(obj)
      return r;
    }, [])
  }

  const result = build(data);
  console.log(result);
```

The group information is not generating correctly. I am trying to figure out that how to get the correct group information. I would really appreciate if you can help me to figure it out.

Comment: How do you get `group` value? Shouldn't it be `"name": "info"` instead of `"name": "main"`

Comment: Those are based on other conditions and not related with "lines" information. That's why I didn't mention it.

Comment: your output json is not valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `reduce` method and create recursive function to build the nested structure.

```js
const data = {"info":{"file1":{"book1":{"lines":{"102:0":["102:0"],"105:4":["106:4"],"106:4":["107:1","108:1"]}}}}}

function build(data) {
  return Object.entries(data).reduce((r, [key, value]) => {
    const obj = {}

    if (key !== 'lines') {
      obj.name = key;
      obj.children = build(value)
    } else {
      if (!obj.lines) obj.lines = [];
      Object.entries(value).forEach(([k, v]) => {
        obj.lines.push([k, ...v].map(e => e.split(':').shift()))
      })
    }

    r.push(obj)
    return r;
  }, [])
}

const result = build(data);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand the logic behind `group` property, so you might need to add more info for that, but for the rest, you can try these 2 functions that recursively transform the object into what you are trying to get.

```js
var a = {"info":{"file1":{"book1":{"lines":{"102:0":["102:0"],"105:4":["106:4"],"106:4":["107:1","108:1"]}}}}};

var transform = function (o) {
    return Object.keys(o)
            .map((k) => { 
                  return {"name": k, "children": (k === "lines" ? parseLines(o[k]) : transform(o[k])) } 
              }
            )
}

var parseLines = function (lines) {
    return Object.keys(lines)
            .map(v => [v.split(':')[0], ...(lines[v].map(l => l.split(":")[0]))])
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(transform(a)[0], null, 2));
```